# Raspberry pi LED-switch code with HiveMQ using python

Tags: python-3.x

#I need help with HiveMQ using python 3.10.6
#I want to send my text file to the broker.
#please give me some tips on how to transfer this text file as my message payload.

Answer (score 0):

In MQTT you cannot send the whole text file as a "file". Instead you can only send messages. Meaning if you want to replicate the same "file" on the other end, you need to parse out all the text inside the file and send it as a payload, and later use a buffer at the other end to capture all these payload and form a file with it.

Maximum size of MQTT payload can be 256 MB. So most probably you will be able to send the full text inside the text file as a message to other end. But you have to use file operations to read it and save as txt file in the other end.

I hope this was useful.

Thank You

NAVEEN PS

Comment: Glad you found this useful